# Reading a CSV file to pandas works in windows, not in ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, raspberry-pi4

I have written some scrip in python using windows and want to run it in my raspberry with Ubuntu.

I am reading a csv file with line separator new line. When I load the df I use the following code:

`dfaux = pd.read_csv(r'/home/ubuntu/Downloads/data.csv', sep=';')`

which loads a df with just one row. I have also tried including the argument  `lineterminator = '\n\t'` which throws this error message:

ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported

In windows I see the line breaks in the csv file, whereas when I open it with mousepad in ubuntu I don't see the line breakers, but I see the columns color coded.

How could I read properly the csv?

Thanks!

Comment: IS it possible that this is a line separator enoding problem? Could you trz to convert the csv to unix style line endings? You can use for example dos2unix for that.

Comment: I did the conversion using dos2unix from the terminal, with the same result

Answer (score 1):

Well, at then end I solved it by changing the explorer I was using to download the csv file with webdriver from Firefox to Chrome, not sure what´s the reason behind but maybe this will help if you have the same issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an issue with the difference in line endings between Windows and... well, everything else. Windows uses a two-character line terminator, "\r\n" (carriage return, followed by newline), whereas Linux and Mac and everything else use just "\n".

Two easy fixes:

1. Using `read_csv(..., engine='python')` should remedy the issue. You may also need to specify `read_csv(..., lineterminator='\r\n')`, but based on the error message you're getting, it looks like it's auto-detecting that anyway. ([Function docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html))
2. Fix the file before sending it to Pandas. Something like:

   ```
    import io
    csv_data = open(r'/home/ubuntu/Downloads/data.csv').read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
    dfaux = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))
   ```

Comment: Thank for the comments. Fix 1 is not changing the result, whereas fix 2 is throwing OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: ... seems it is trying to rename the file with all the data inside the file itself

Comment: @Carlos Fixed #2 to use StringIO instead so the string looks like a file object. For #1, did you add both arguments, or only the ``engine`` one?